# call prepareforsegue after user finished editing uitextfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, segue, viewcontroller

How do i pass the value of the text from the UITextField into another view controller. Currently, when I override the `func prepareForSegue()`, it is being called before the user finished editing the textfield, so the value passed is always null.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of ways to go about this:

1. Directly access the `text` value of your `TextField` instead of your model, which sounds like it is updated after `didFinishEditing`
2. Instead of updating your model only on `didFinishEditing` you can update it every time the text changes by implementing `internal func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool`, and getting the new value with `let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)`

Comment: However, `override func prepareForSegue()` is being called before the user finishes editing the textfield. Is there anyway I can make it so that this function is called after user edits the textfield? Do i put this function inside `didFinishEditing` ?

Comment: Please read both of my answers, which will work without getting hacky. You **could** instead implement `internal func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool` and return `false`, and then at the end of `didFinishEditing` call `performSegue`, but that would be a very bad idea in my opinion.